# how to send additional data along with res.redirect in NodeJS Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As we can send additional data or "message" along with res.render like in the example below, can we do the same in res.redirect?
res.render("dashboard", {message:"Welcome to the dashboard page"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of ways in which you can pass data around in a redirection but the most right way is to use `query string` to pass your data. as said you always need to make sure that your URL is properly [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
app.get('/redirect', function(req, res) {
  var string = encodeURIComponent('something that would break');
  res.redirect('/your/redirection/url/?data=' + string);
});
```

Comment: can we send a JSON in place of the string?

Answer (score 2):

you can use session for passing data with redirect

flash package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash

```js
app.get('/flash', function(req, res){
  // Set a flash message by passing the key, followed by the value, to req.flash().
  req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')
  res.redirect('/');
});
 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // Get an array of flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
  res.render('index', { messages: req.flash('info') });
});
```